# SharePoint 2007 - Upgrading directly to SP2

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, upgrade

I have a SharePoint 2007 environment which has not been updated for quite long time (Aug 2007 CU installed).

Now we are in the process of migrating those SharePoint 2007 instance onto SharePoint 2010 farm.  One of the prerequisites are to update our SharePoint 2007 instances to at least SP2,

Is it advisable to upgrade directly onto SP2 instead of going through SP1 --> SP2 path ?

I read in Microsoft site that SP2 includes all the SP1 related changes (of course it should)

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance...

Sudhir Kesharwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official blog from Microsoft SharePoint Team, which says - Yes, you can.

Visit this blog for all detailed steps that you need to watchout for - 
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/04/28/announcing-service-pack-2-for-office-sharepoint-server-2007-and-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

As the blog says, SP2 can be installed directly on any build before Febrary 2009.

**NOTE:** Take DB backups on each step of your upgradation process, so that you can revert to the previous working condition without any issues. Also, remember to run the SharePoint configuration wizard or psconfig in command line on each server in your farm for complete upgradation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepu,  that surely helps me in taking right decision.